# Is it possible to filter tumblr posts of a blog to a particular author?

Tags: tumblr

Is there a url to the author's page for a particular tumblr blog?

In the [tumblr docs](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes) the author url just links to the author's own tumblr blog.

Ie, Is it possible to filter posts of a blog to a particular author?

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure the only filtering you can do on posts (at least in the basic format, I know nothing of the API) is using tags. If the posts aren't tagged for author, then you probably can't. As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682225/how-to-make-links-homepage-only-vs-site-wide-on-tumblr):

> Tumblr has only two main types of page:
>
> ```
>     PermalinkPage
>     IndexPage
> ```
>
> IndexPage include 3 sub-types:
>
> ```
>     TagPage
>     DayPage
>     SearchPage
> ```

If what you want to filter for can't be achieved by these (and I'm fairly sure filtering using `{PostAuthorURL}`/`{PostAuthorName}` is not possible), then you can't do it with the base tumblr theme tools. If it's possible with Javascript and the API, I don,t have the competence to tell.